# updating mongodb using new json object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb

im trying to update my mongodb using a new json object i got from the browser but the update method doesnt do anything (i also tried to use updateOne and it still didnt work).

my server code:

```
var express = require("express");
var path = require("path");
var url = require("url");

var app = express(); // express.createServer();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

app.use(express.static(__dirname));

var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
, format = require('util').format;

var insertMsg, Collection;
var socketMap = {};

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/EladGuy', function(err, db) {
    if(err) 
        throw err;
    Collection = db.collection('messages');
    console.log("connected to DB");
    insertMsg = function (saveJson) {
        console.log("Start Saving...");
        db.collection('messages').insertOne(saveJson);
        console.log("Finish saving successfuly...");
    };
    removeMessages = function(msg, callback) {
        db.collection('messages').deleteMany(
            { "name": msg }, 
            function(err, results) {
                console.log(results);
                callback();
            }
        );
    };
    updateMessage = function(msg,callback) {
        db.collection('messages').updateOne({"name":msg.name},{$set: msg},function(err, results) {
                console.log(msg.name);
                console.log(results);
                callback();
            });
    };
});

app.get("/TestUpdate", function(request, response) {
    var screenId = request.query.id;
    console.log("Updating station number: " + screenId);
    var newMsg = {  
        "screensId":[parseInt(screenId)],
        "name":"msg6",
        "text":["Won the lottary?","Want to invest your money?","Shulberg investment company","Your money is important to us!"],
        "images":["http://thefilipinoexpat.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/04_investment.jpg"],
        "template":"/html/templateA.html",
        "msgTime":5000,
        "timeFrame":[
            { "startDate" : [2016,0,1], "endDate" : [2016,11,31], "days" : [0,1,2,3,4,5,6], "startTime" : 6, "endTime" : 23},
            { "startDate" : [2016,0,1], "endDate" : [2016,11,31], "days" : [5], "startTime" : 13, "endTime" : 20}]  }
    insertMsg(newMsg);
    if (socketMap[parseInt(screenId)] != undefined) {
        socketMap[parseInt(screenId)].emit('messageUpdate', newMsg);
    }
    response.send("SUCCESS!");
});

app.get("/screen=:screenNum", function(request, response) {
    response.sendFile(__dirname + '/station/station.html');
});

app.get("/html/:template", function(request, response) {
    var template = request.params.template;
    response.sendFile(__dirname + '/station/' + template);
});

app.get("/stationPreview=:screenNum", function(request, response) {
    response.sendFile(__dirname + '/station/stationPreview.html');
});

app.get("/*", function(request, response) {
    response.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('sendId', function(stationId) {
        socketMap[parseInt(stationId)] = socket;
    });
    socket.on('getMessagesByScreen', function(screenId) {
        res = [];
        Collection.find({"screensId":{'$eq': parseInt(screenId)}}).toArray(function(err, docs) {
            docs.forEach(function(doc) {
                res.push(doc);
            });
            socket.emit('sendMessages', res);
        });
    });
    socket.on('getAllMessages',function(unUsed) {
        res = [];
        Collection.find().toArray(function(err, docs) {
            docs.forEach(function(doc) {
                res.push(doc);
            });
            socket.emit('sendAllMessages', res);
        });
    });
    socket.on('deleteMessage', function(msg) {
        removeMessages(msg, function() {
            socket.emit('DeleteSuccessed', null);
        });
    });
    socket.on('getMessage', function(msg) {
        Msg = [];
        Collection.find({"name":{'$eq': msg}}).toArray(function(err, docs) {
            docs.forEach(function(doc) {
                Msg.push(doc);
            });
            socket.emit('sendMessage', Msg);
        });
    });
    socket.on('getStations', function(unUsed) {
        Collection.distinct("screensId", function(err, stationsArray) {
            socket.emit('sendStations', stationsArray);
        });
    });
    socket.on('EditMessage', function(update){
        updateMessage(update,function(){
            console.log("UPDATE SUCEES!!!");
        });
    });
});

server.listen(8080, function() {
    console.log("Messages Application Express node js server listening on port %d...", this.address().port);
});
```

as you may see in my socket im using:"on('EditMessage')" when this happening the server activate the function:"updateMessage" which gets the update which is a json object just like the other ones stored in the mongodb.
my update should find the name of the message (which is uniq to each message) and update the message.
when i do so i get on console from the undifined  and the the message "UPDATE SUCCESS" and when i check again i see that it didnt do anything.